# Problema con Select2 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de usar **Select2** para mi pagina, puse en el `<head>` los respectivos links y llamé a `Select2`, pero no funciona.

**Abrí el inspector del navegador y me aparece esto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto los enlaces que puse dentro del `<head>`**

```
<!--cdn de select2-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pon el código y los mensajes de error **como texto**, incluyendo un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, así podremos hacer pruebas y ayudarte a resolver el problema. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que **NO VEO JQUERY.** estás llamando a Select2, que es una librería de Jquery, y si no llamas primero a Jquery entonces Select2 no se ejecutará correctamente.

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

**1-** Como observación, no es recomendable poner los scripts en el `<head>` puesto que tu página no se mostraría (renderizarse) correctamente hasta que los scripts se hayan cargado. Lo recomendable es ponerlos al final del código pero antes del `</body>`. Lo que sí deberías poner es el `.css` es decir:

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

**2- Poner correctamente los scripts:**

```
<!--PRIMERO LLAMAMOS A JQUERY-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--LUEGO A SELECT2-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Y listo, eso debería solucionar tu problema.

Comment: gracias funciono  con tu respuesta :)